# How to paste matched text multiple times?

Tags: python, notepad++, regex, android-studio

I have text:

```
0 -> {
    }
    1 -> {
    }
    2 -> {
    }
    3 -> {
    }
```

and I want to copy and paste this text multiple times at once with Notepad++ Python Script, Android Studio or other tools to be like this:

```
0 -> {
    }
    1 -> {
    }
    2 -> {
    }
    3 -> {
    }
0 -> {
    }
    1 -> {
    }
    2 -> {
    }
    3 -> {
    }
0 -> {
    }
    1 -> {
    }
    2 -> {
    }
    3 -> {
    }
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Unclear: What's wrong with copy-paste?

Comment: If I want to make 100 pastes instantly, some script would be faster.

Comment: Just do 7 times: `CTRL-A`, `CTRL-C`, `CTRL-V`.

Answer (score 0):

(I'm assuming that you are on Windows.)

Here is a fancy answer, that even prompts you for the number of times
to paste. Ensure you have the right text in the clipboard before
pasting 100 times.

The tool is the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following example script will map
<kbd>F12</kbd>
to the script:

```
F12::
InputBox, number, Paste count, Please input the number of times to paste
Loop, %number%
    Send, ^v
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit. To have it run on login,
place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Answer (score 0):

1. With Notepad++, create a python script and enter the code below. Save it.
2. Open your file, then run the script.

```py
editor.selectAll()
editor.copy()

for x in range(1, 6):
    editor.paste()
```

All texts of an open file are selected and copied; then pasted 5 times in this example.

Answer (score 0):

Highlight all > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> > 'knock' urself out. /(^_^)

Please share if it works/not.